# Plone full text indexing in pdfs on win7

Tags: search, plone

I installed Plone 4.2.1 using the Windows Installer on my DELL XPS15 with Windows 7 64bit.  Then made ​​an update to 4.2.4, it's running well so far everything. I've created my first page, change the logo.

But, if I include a PDF document as a file, the contents of that file cannot be found when searching. According to the description it should work but the full-text search in PDF's.  Am I missing something there yet, or you have to set somewhere to activate or what?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the XPDF package to convert PDF to text for Plone to be able to index the contents.

Download it from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html, where you'll find a pre-compiled Windows binary.